# How do I bind a variable in svelte to an variable within my dropdown object?

Tags: binding, svelte

I'm new to svelte and trying to figure out how to modify a project created using it. The current project has a number of sliders bound to different variables, I'm looking for a way to implement a dropdown that also alters some of those variables. I'm uncertain how to bind the var to a quantity within the data object. Let's say the variable I want to effect is R0, how do I change R0 to Repro when the dropdown is chosen ?

```js
let variants  = [
        { id: 1, text: 'Wuhan', repro: 2.5 },
        { id: 2, text: 'Alpha', repro: 2.5 },
        { id: 3, text: 'Delta', repro: 3 }
    ];

<select bind:value={selected}">
    {#each variants as variant}
        <option value={variant}>
            {variant.text}
        </option>
    {/each}
</select>
```

Comment: Not sure if I could understand your problem. What is `R0` in your code? 
Your variable `selected` should be bound to the selected option. To access the corresponding `repro` attribute, just use `selected.repro`.
Maybe declare `selected` after instantiating `variants` with `let selected;`

Comment: And there is an extra `"` in your code, after `bind:value={selected}`. Check out this tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/select-bindings

Comment: Seems to work like expected: https://svelte.dev/repl/25279c350ab04f5886b8296d32cced89?version=3.41.0.

Answer (score 0):

With credit to @johannchopin, I guess

changing `$: console.log(selected)` in [his REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/25279c350ab04f5886b8296d32cced89?version=3.41.0)

to `R0 = selected?.repro || null` will do as desired ([Amended REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e69c544465a6420f841061c776ac79de?version=3.41.0))